# How to search for common elements among csv files and save the entire row

Tags: python, csv

I am completely new to python...

I need to search in a column of two csv files (Workbook1 and Workbook2), whether they share anything. Then I would like to store the entire row into a file, possibly a csv. Below is where I am blocked:

```
stack = []
import csv
with open('/Users/freemanlab/Downloads/Workbook1.csv', newline= '') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=':', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for row in reader:
        stack.append(row)

list1 = stack

stack = []
import csv
with open('/Users/freemanlab/Downloads/Workbook2.csv', newline= '') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=':', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for row in reader:
        stack.append(row)

list2 = stack

matches = [item for item in list1 if item in list2]

print(matches)
print('Number of matches is...')
print(len(matches))

with open('/Users/freemanlab/Downloads/matches.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerows(matches)
```

I know that in this way, it works only for the first column of a csv with one column only, but I would like to work it on more complex file, for example, in the second column of a file with many more.

Finally I would like to search in a third file (Workbook3) whether the common content is found there as well, and when it finds it, store the entire row into a csv.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Do you mean that the value in *any* column of `Workbook1` matches with *any* column in `Workbook2`, or just if column 1 matches column 1, or column 2 matches column 2 etc?

Comment: quick question: how big are your workbooks?

Comment: Your code finds the rows in workbook 1 that match a row in workbook 2, and by match, I mean the contents of _every_ column in the rows from each — so it's a confusing when you say "it works only for the first column of a csv with one column only". Please clarify.

Comment: Looks like you have a good start. You understand what you want to do well enough to _verbalize_ it and you can see that your solution is lacking. Try tho write a solution that matches your requirements and ask a new question when you run into trouble.